# Extend laptop display on two screens

Tags: laptop, display

I have an [ASUS ZenBook Pro 14 UX480FD](https://www.asus.com/uk/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-Pro-14-UX480FD/).

When I bought it, I didn't know about Thunderbolt and I hadn't seen that the USB-C port of this laptop didn't allow Thunderbolt.

Now, I'd like to add 2 external screens, but my laptop embeds only one HDMI port. I've read that I could use an external video card like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-USB-Dual-HDMI-Adapter/dp/B0725K1MHH/ref=sr_1_1).

Could you confirm for me that it will work?

If it works, will I be restrained with graphics? (on SolidWorks or light video mounting)

Will it work if I plug the video card into a hub like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Lenovo-Aluminum-Adapter-Compatible-Devices/dp/B07DCQ3FBL/ref=sr_1_4) and plug the hub into the USB-C port of my laptop?

Comment: This is worth testing at a walk-in store ( Best Buy , Fry's Electronics , etc ) before buying anything.

Answer (score 0):

Unless someone has tried this combination before, you may have difficulties getting the answer you may want, however:

Forget the USB to dual HDMI adapter, the second link you have provided shows a usb 3c hub with a built in HDMI port too, using this would save you the money having to buy the first device.

Also I would expect the laptop GFX card do the processing power for the external monitors.

Answer (score -1):

Plug your HDMI CABLE first and than there is two ways to extend your display on another screen the short key is (Press window button along with 'P' you can see the four options to (extend, duplicate, only laptop, only other screen) your screen to another. and the second way is to right click on your desktop and click on screen resolution you can find option in it also.